# Finding value of $f(1,2)$ from a function.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

If $f(x,y)=x+y×f(y,x)$ then find $f(1,2)$.

Comment: Try to solve it own and if you have tried then give your try result.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Given that, $f(x,y)=x+y×f(y,x)$

$f(1,2)=1+2×f(2,1)
=> f(2,1)=[f(1,2)-1]/2$

$f(2,1)=2+1×f(1,2)$

$=> [f(1,2)-1]/2 =2+1×f(1,2)$

$=> f(1,2)-1 =4+2×f(1,2)$

$=> f(1,2) =5+2×f(1,2)$

$=> f(1,2) = -5$

So, the value is $-5$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(x,y)=x+yf(y,x)$$
therefore
$$f(y,x)=y+xf(x,y)$$
rearranging and plugging this result back into the original equation we get
$$\frac{f(y,x)-y}{x}=x+yf(y,x)$$
rearranging again we get
$$f(y, x) = x^2+yxf(y,x)+y$$
leaving us with
$$f(y, x)(1-yx) = x^2+y$$
$$f(y, x) = \frac{x^2+y}{1-yx}$$
or interchanging variables to get $f(x,y)$ we get
$$f(x, y) = \frac{y^2+x}{1-yx}$$
This is our closed form!

Now all the is left to do is plug in the values $x = 1$ and $y=2$, to get
$$f(1, 2) = \frac{2^2+1}{1-2}$$
$$ = -5$$

Comment: Why did this receive a downvote? This answers the question and gives a closed form for $f(x,y)$. Please, if something can be improved, leave a comment and let me know instead of just downvoting

Comment: I would guess that you’re being downvoted due to the poor quality of the question. Often users of this site are against posting answers to low-quality, low-context questions to discourage them from being posted. Your answer itself is well-written.